# Difference between output NSDate from NSDateFormatter and NSDateComponents

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

```
let stringWithDate = "2015-07-16T6:08:32.000Z"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 2015
dateComponents.month = 7
dateComponents.day = 16
dateComponents.hour = 6
dateComponents.minute = 8
dateComponents.second = 32

let dateFromDateFormatter = dateFormatter.dateFromString(stringWithDate) //"Jul 16, 2015, 8:08 AM"
let dateFromDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(dateComponents)! //"Jul 16, 2015, 6:08 AM"

dateFromDateFormatter == dateFromDateComponents //false
```

Why these dates are not the same?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I have found a solution:

`NSDateFormatter` includes information about `NSTimeZone` *(`Z` at the end of Sting)* while `NSDateComponents` doesn't. So we need to simple inform `dateComponents` about `NSTimeZone`:

```
dateComponents.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

The output dates are now the same.

Adding the same information to `dateFormatter`:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

doesn't change anything, because there is information about `NSTimeZone` yet.